# putting a maximum and minimum limit with a timer using buttons

Tags: c#

I have a timer, it uses 3 labels to show the numbers linked with 6 buttons, 3 to increase time, 3 to decrease time where each pair of up and down buttons controls either hours, minutes or seconds. I want to set a limit on the hours of 2, and set a limit on both minutes and seconds of 59

Comment: Are you stuck somewhere or haven't started yet? You usually post a question once you are stuck, then someone will help you continue with your work

Comment: Those are lofty goals, but we can't help with just that description.. Please show your code and tell us where you're stuck - then we can help. That's the way Stack Overflow works.

Comment: **Don't** use Labels and Buttons.  Use a [NumericUpDown Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown(v=vs.110).aspx) which allows you to set a Minimum and Maximum values, and has the up/down ability already built-in.